# Multiplatform C++ cross-compiler

Tags: c++, architecture, workflow, cross-compiling

How can I build a cross-compiler for a C++ library to target many platforms on a single build server?

The cross-compiler should be able to build the library for (at least) {Windows 7, Mac OS X, Ubuntu 11.04} × {32 bit, 64 bit} × {Debug, Release}. I don't care if the whole build from scratch takes forever or if the `gcc` binary is 1 GB. If the cross-compiler cannot be a single executable, what is the workflow I should use to compile (and recompile) my library?

The host machine would be a Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: If you need Mac OS X then the only viable solution for doing all this on a single server would be a Mac OS X server running Ubuntu and Windows in two VMs.

Comment: Suppose I don't need Mac OS X. Basically, there's no way to have a `./build.sh` to do it? I have to do it manually in VMs?

Comment: Considering the complexity it may be cheaper (if you factor in your salary and the extra time to set up this system) to buy one machine for each platform and just build on the appropriate platforms.

Comment: Do you want to **build** a *compiler* or compiler a program for different platforms?

Comment: Updated the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building cross-compiler is quite well covered in [OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler). For Windows, you can use mingw packages in your distro's repository

Answer (score 0):

Windows host + [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) + GCC (mingw) + Gnu Make (or complementary build script solution) + MSVC8/9

You can have teamcity automate the building of everything for you, GCC will let you build targets in all DBG/REL, 32/64 bit, MacOS/Linux permutations. MSVC8/9 test for cross-compiler compatibilities.

Comment: Continuous integration is not the actual problem. It's the compilers that I need. Otherwise, I already have a `buildbot` that compiles fine for the local machine.