# Multiplatform IDE

Tags: c++, ide, workflow, cross-compiling

I recently realized I'm making it unnecessarily hard on myself to use 4 different IDEs, for every combination of (develop on Windows, develop on Linux)x(program runs on ARM, program runs on local x86 PC).
Currently, every time I switch between an ARM project and a x86 project (often a console app to pre-calculate lookup tables for the ARM project), I switch between IDEs.

If I already have [YAGARTO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/yagarto/) installed on my Windows PC, what's the best way to set up (another?) [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) to compile C++ code natively for my PC?

- Is it better to somehow install 2 copies of Eclipse CDT, one set up to create ARM binaries, the other set up to create x86 binaries? How?
- Is it better to install Eclipse CDT once, then somehow tell it to compile this project into an ARM binary, and that project into a x86 console app? How?
- Is there some other IDE that understands that different projects run on different CPUs? What?

( [Multiplatform C++ cross-compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980397/multiplatform-c-cross-compiler) talks about building multiple cross-compilers. But I'm missing the next step: Once I have a few cross-compilers built, how do I hook an IDE up to them?)

Comment: you don't need 2 separate IDEs... you need to configure your projects properly, either via your own makefile or via eclipse's project options (eclipse can manage different build configurations for you)

Comment: did you think of using 1 ide only to edit the source, and use cmake as the build system? cmake sghould easily handle all platforms/configs you have

Comment: Get 10 more fingers and follow the happy group of Emacs users! Good thing : you use the same shortcut on all environments, you customize once, use everywhere and it links to (almost) everything... once you get use to the elisp way of thinking.

Comment: @stijn: Cross-compiling with CMake is nigh impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch toolchain configurations within Eclipse based on targets or projects. There's no need to switch IDEs, it's just a matter of associating toolchains correctly.

- http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_build_toolchain.htm
- http://www.frozentux.net/2008/10/switching-gnu-toolchains-in-eclipse-the-easy-way/
- http://eclipsebook.in/c-cpp-development/building-code/build-eclipse-managed/